# SQL Query across tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, conditional-statements, toad

I am trying to extract data from a system comprised of various tables where I am using one table as a primary list and then trying to select multiple events from another table which all relate to the single line in the first table.

The Orders table and Processing tables are constructed;

```
Orders
Ref         | Fruit     | Shapes        | Colours   | OrderDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------
22222       | Apple     | Round         | Red       | 2020/02/23
33333       | Pear      | Round         | Green     | 2020/02/23
44444       | Banana    | Long          | Yellow    | 2020/02/23

Processing
Fruit       | ProcessID     | ProcessDateTime
-----------------------------------------+----------------------------
Apple       | Receipt       | 2020/02/23 09:34:03
Apple       | Repack        | 2020/02/23 10:15:23
Apple       | Dispatch      | 2020/02/23 10:32:11
Pear        | Receipt       | 2020/03/23 08:34:55
Pear        | Repack        | 2020/02/23 09:08:43
Pear        | Dispatch      | 2020/02/23 10:43:21
Banana      | Receipt       | 2020/02/23 07:23:32
Banana      | Repack        | 2020/02/23 09:33:28
Banana      | Dispatch      | 2020/02/23 11:38:01
```

And the data extracted should be similar to the format;

```
Ref     | Fruit | DateOrdered   | DateReceipt           | DateRepack            | DateDispatch
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22222   | Apple | 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 09:34:03   | 2020/02/23 10:15:23   | 2020/02/23 10:32:11
33333   | Pear  | 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 08:34:55   | 2020/02/23 09:08:43   | 2020/02/23 10:43:21
44444   | Banana| 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 07:23:32   | 2020/02/23 09:33:28   | 2020/02/23 11:38:01
```

The code I have created will begin similar to;

```
SELECT
Orders.Ref,
Orders.Fruit,
Orders.Shapes,
Orders.Colours,
.Now I want to select each ProcessID for each Ref and ProcessDateTime date for each of the processes in Processing. 
There are 3 processes in the example here, but it will not necesarily always
be 3, it will vary in number of processes.

FROM Orders
LEFT INNER JOIN Processing ON Processing.Fruit = Orders.Fruit

WHERE
Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN date1 AND date2;  -- These dates will be identified when running...
```

I have looked online around conditional joins, but am struggling a bit here and any help would be most welcome, thanks!

Thank you Gordon for your response to this issue, it is very nearly working correctly for me except for the fact that each of the entries in table processing is being placed on a separate line, rather than combining on the single line as I had hoped.
Using your solution, I am getting;

```
Ref     | Fruit | DateOrdered   | DateReceipt           | DateRepack            | DateDispatch
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22222   | Apple | 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 09:34:03   |                       |                   
22222   | Apple | 2020/02/23    |                       | 2020/02/23 10:15:23   |                    
22222   | Apple | 2020/02/23    |                       |                       | 2020/02/23 10:32:11
33333   | Pear  | 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 08:34:55   |                       | 
33333   | Pear  | 2020/02/23    |                       | 2020/02/23 09:08:43   |
33333   | Pear  | 2020/02/23    |                       |                       | 2020/02/23 10:43:21
44444   | Banana| 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 07:23:32   |                       | 
44444   | Banana| 2020/02/23    |                       | 2020/02/23 09:33:28   | 
44444   | Banana| 2020/02/23    |                       |                       | 2020/02/23 11:38:01
```

Rather than the result which i wanted to achieve below;

```
Ref     | Fruit | DateOrdered   | DateReceipt           | DateRepack            | DateDispatch
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22222   | Apple | 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 09:34:03   | 2020/02/23 10:15:23   | 2020/02/23 10:32:11
33333   | Pear  | 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 08:34:55   | 2020/02/23 09:08:43   | 2020/02/23 10:43:21
44444   | Banana| 2020/02/23    | 2020/02/23 07:23:32   | 2020/02/23 09:33:28   | 2020/02/23 11:38:01
```

Comment: You don't clearly sayhow output is a function of input or what problem you are having. Please do plus give the rest of a [mre]. [ask]

Comment: I do not understand your point here, what more do you need? I have stated what the tables contents are and i have stated what the output requirements are, and they are direct data extractions from the combined tables. The issue i am having is that i do not know how to achieve a multiple line read from the second table as referenced by each lin in the first table.

Comment: My first comment is clear & correct, contrary to your comment. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.Ref, o.Fruit, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.ProcessID = 'RECEIPT' THEN ProcessDateTime END) as receipt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.ProcessID = 'REPACK' THEN ProcessDateTime END) as repack,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.ProcessID = 'DISPATCH' THEN ProcessDateTime END) as dispatch
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     Processing p
     ON p.Fruit = o.Fruit
WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN date1 AND date2
GROUP BY o.Ref, o.Fruit;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, your solution almost works but not quite. I am not quite sure how to use this site (and seem to be continually getting told off) but I have edited my original question to show the result of your suggested solution and the continued issue that I am having. Thanks again.

Comment: @SBalmer . . . I changed the query so it only aggregates by `ref` and `fruit`, which should fix the problem.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - that worked perfectly, thank you so much!! Not just in solving my issue but for expanding my knowledge of conditional aggregation!